# How to explicitly pass an Ordering to an implicit enrichment

Tags: scala

I have defined the following implicit enrichment of the Seq

```
class OrderedSeqEnricher[T <% Ordered[T]](seq: Seq[T]) {

    def binarySearch(e: T): Int = binarySearch(e, 0, seq.length)

    private def binarySearch(e: T, start: Int, end: Int): Int =
        if (start < end) {
            val mid = start + (end - start) / 2
            if (e < seq(mid)) binarySearch(e, start, mid)
            else if (e > seq(mid)) binarySearch(e, mid + 1, end)
            else mid
        }
        else -start
}

implicit def toOrderedSeqEnricher[T <% Ordered[T]](seq: Seq[T]) = new OrderedSeqEnricher(seq)
```

The problem I have is that there is a case where I want to use my seq to store ids which are used to look up objects in a tree and then compare these objects. Something like:

```
implicit def ordering: Ordering[Int] = (i1: Int, i2: Int) =>
    if (tree(i1).myCompare(tree(i2)) < 0) -1 else 1
```

Is there a way I can explicitly specify that this is the ordering to use rather than them being treated as simple ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can combine a class and an `implicit def` which just constructs it by using `implicit class`:

   ```
   implicit class OrderedSeqEnricher[T <% Ordered[T]](seq: Seq[T]) { ... }
   ```
2. To quote `Ordered` documentation:

   > A trait for data that have a single, natural ordering. See scala.math.Ordering before using this trait for more information about whether to use scala.math.Ordering instead.

   So you can't use an `Ordering` with `<% Ordered[T]`. Instead prefer `: Ordering` (and I'd do so in general unless you have some very specific reason to use `Ordered`):

   ```
   implicit class OrderedSeqEnricher[T : Ordering](seq: Seq[T]) { ... }
   ```

Then you can pass `ordering` explicitly as

```
 new OrderedSeqEnricher(someIntSeq)(ordering).binarySearch(...)
```

Or put the parameter on the methods instead of the class:

```
implicit class OrderedSeqEnricher[T](seq: Seq[T]) {

    def binarySearch(e: T)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): Int = binarySearch(e, 0, seq.length)

    private def binarySearch(e: T, start: Int, end: Int)(implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): Int =
        if (start < end) {
            val mid = start + (end - start) / 2
            if (e < seq(mid)) binarySearch(e, start, mid)
            else if (e > seq(mid)) binarySearch(e, mid + 1, end)
            else mid
        }
        else -start
}

someIntSeq.binarySearch(...)(ordering)
```

Another potentially good idea would be to make ids a separate value class from `Int`s (preventing any operations which are meaningless for your ids, e.g. arithmetic):

```
class Id(value: Int) extends AnyVal { ... }

object Id {
  implicit def ordering(implicit tree: Tree): Ordering[Id] = (i1: Id, i2: Id) =>
    // assumes trees are changed to apply(Id) instead of apply(Int)
    if (tree(i1).myCompare(tree(i2)) < 0) -1 else 1
}
```

Comment: When I try putting the parameter on the methods the comparison parts will not compile: "...value < is not a member of type parameter T..."

Comment: So I should rather be doing ordering.compare(e, seq(mid)) < 0 I guess?

Comment: To enable operators for Ordering, `import scala.math.Ordering.Implicits.infixOrderingOps` (https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/math/Ordering$$Implicits$.html). I kind of hate this not being in `Predef`. Or yes, use `compare`.